# For C what is the Windows header version for Linux header <sys/io.h> I/O Ports

Tags: c, io, header, include, ioports

For Linux you can include `<sys/io.h>` to have I/O Ports with hardware I assume?

```
outb(...);
outw(...);
inb(...);
```

Which header must I include to have these functions for Windows compilation?

Edit:
[Windows equivalent of `inb()`, `outb()` low-level I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607657/windows-equivalent-of-inb-outb-low-level-i-o) says it's impossible on Windows; you need install a driver on Windows to use a quick fix.

Comment: When you use `<sys/*.h>` headers, you are limiting your portability to other systems. If the `<sys/*.h>` header is defined by POSIX, you mostly limit your portability to other POSIX systems. If the `<sys/*.h>` header is not defined by POSIX (and POSIX does not define `<sys/io.h>`), all bets are off; you have to worry about whether systems providing the same header name provide the same functionality.  So, migration to Windows is going to require you to research how Windows provides the functionality. Assume that it will involve different headers, functions, constants (but you might get lucky).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks I'll just comment these out for now and get back to it later. Thanks alot if you wrote this as a answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, for MS Windows low level io is WinAPI functions like CreateFile, WriteFile and so on.

Comment: Ya this is cpu emulator I think it needs control/access of all hardware to be complete